# Reference to a range in Google Sheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

How can I reference to a range in Google Sheet?

If I want to reference one cell to another I just write on the target cell the formula '=A1' for example, but if I have a range of sheet names A: A! a1: c2 and I want to see the same 6 cells values on sheet B on d5:f6, which formula should I write in cell B!d5 to reference it to A!a1:c2 ?

And if I want to do the same via script, how can I create a reference to a range programmatically?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

> I have a range ... A! a1: c2 and I want to see the same 6 cells values on sheet B on d5:f6

```
=ArrayFormula(A!A1:C2)
```